# What is the command to delete prior n lines in vi?

Tags: linux, vi

5dd will delete the next 5 lines.

Based on cursor position, is there a normal-mode command that will delete the prior n lines?

I've tried several non-working stabs, like $5dd, or !5dd (don't do that). Using Visual mode is not an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The motion to move up a line is `k`, so `4dk`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work: deleting lines numbered (current-4) to (current-1):

`:-4,-1d`